# What is the character set if default_charset is empty

Tags: php, string, character-encoding

In PHP 5.6 onwards the `default_charset` string is set to `"UTF-8"` as explained e.g. [in the `php.ini` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset). It says that the string is empty for earlier versions.

As I am creating a Java library to communicate with PHP, I need to know which values I should expect when a string is handled as bytes internally. What happens if the `default_charset` string is empty and a (literal) string contains characters outside the range of ASCII? Should I expect the default character encoding of the platform, or the character encoding used for the source file?

Comment: You can figure this out yourself by testing, but if I had to guess I would say it just treats it as a binary string.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol If the string is a literal, would it just default to the encoding of the source file? I've got PHP running here, but I would only be validating my own system, not others.

Comment: Yes, I think so. A good way to find out would be to try `é` in a UTF-8 file - do you get `é` or `Ã©`?

Comment: If I just run it on an UTF-8 console with a PHP file that uses UTF-8 as well, then it prints `é`, or even `λ`... But that does not completely answer my question... If I save as Latin and print out `Ã©Î»` then I get the same output though, so that looks like just bytes indeed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Short answer

For literal strings -- always source file encoding. `default_charset` value does nothing here.

#### Longer answer

PHP strings are "binary safe" meaning they do not have any internal string encoding. Basically string in PHP are just buffers of bytes.

For literal strings e.g. `$s = "Ä"` this means that string will contain whatever bytes were saved in file between quotes. If file was saved in **UTF-8** this will be equivalent to `$s = "\xc3\x84"`, if file was saved in **ISO-8859-1** (latin1) this will be equivalent to `$s = "\xc4"`.

Setting `default_charset` value does not affect bytes stored in strings in any way.

#### What does `default_charset` do then?

Some functions, that have to deal with strings as *text* and are encoding aware, accept `$encoding` as argument (usually optional). This tells the function what encoding the text is encoded in a string.

Before PHP 5.6 default value of these optional `$encoding` arguments were either in function definition (e.g. `htmlspecialchars()`) or configurable in various php.ini settings for each extension separately (e.g. `mbstring.internal_encoding`, `iconv.input_encoding`).

In PHP 5.6 new php.ini setting `default_charset` was introduced. Old settings were deprecated and all functions that accept optional `$encoding` argument should now default to `default_charset` value when encoding is not specified explicitly.

However, developer is left responsible to make sure that text in string is actually encoded in encoding that was specified.

---

Links:

- [Details of the String Type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.details)
  More details on nature of PHP strings (does not mention `default_charset` at the time of writing).
- [New features in PHP 5.6: Default character encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.default-encoding)
  Short introduction of new `default_charset` option in PHP 5.6 release notes.
- [Deprecated features in PHP 5.6: iconv and mbstring encoding settings](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.deprecated.php#migration56.deprecated.iconv-mbstring-encoding)
  List of deprecated php.ini options in favour of `default_chaset` option.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find any link to a definitive source for this, but a quick validation on the functions you've provided shows it should be correct. If there is a source within the PHP documentation I would be happy to know about it.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes-owlstead Yes, of course. Added some links.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you should **not** rely on the internal encoding. The internal character encoding can be seen/set with [mb_internal_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php).

**example phpinfo()**

- PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5
- default_charset  no value

**file1.php**

```
<?php
$string = "e";
echo mb_internal_encoding(); //ISO-8859-1
```

**file2.php**

```
<?php
$string = "É";
echo mb_internal_encoding(); //ISO-8859-1
```

both files will output **ISO-8859-1** if you do not change the internal encoding manually.

```
<?php
echo bin2hex("ö"); //c3b6 (utf-8)
```

Getting the hex of this character returns UTF-8 encoding. If you save the file using UTF-8 the string in this example will have 2 bytes, even if the internal encoding is not set to UTF-8. Therefore you should rely on the character encoding used for the source file.