# Why font error UTF-8 when upgrade new version from 5.4 to 5.6

Tags: utf-8, updates, php-5.6

I have recently updated my PHP to 5.6 (from 5.4) and something strange happened.

My website suddenly displays UTF-8 characters incorrectly even though. I'm using the Meta Tag `<meta charset="utf-8">` and I set default php.ini is: `default_charset = ""` because version 5.6 default support charset=UTF-8, but when I get data from database MySQL, this doesn't work.

My data:

[image: view my images database]

And view response:

[image: view images response]

I have been tried much case but did not work, how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

We also try config and read some orther materials as:

[What is the character set if default_charset is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345626/what-is-the-character-set-if-default-charset-is-empty)

[PHP 5.6 default_charset change may break HTML output](https://www.saotn.org/php-56-default_charset-change-may-break-html-output/)

However our website has corrupted fonts. @@. 'So everyone check and support for us.

Thanks alot